# can't call javascript in <script>

Tags: javascript

This is an extremely simple question but possibly so simple I cannot find the answer online.  I am first assuming that this is correct

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function sayit(){
alert('hello');
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button onclick="sayit()">Say it</button>
</body>
</html>
```

This code should work shouldn't it?

Comment: Does it work?  What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Perfect time to try out http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Works for me. Must be a browser issue, specifically regarding that `language` attribute.

Comment: Maybe you've JavaScript switched off in your browser...?

Answer (score 1):

remove the language attribute. and also. what browser are you using? in chrome this code works normally.